# Subword/Transient-Mark Highlighting Issues in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have Global Subword Mode enabled, but I am trying to get <kbd>Ctrl+Left/Right</kbd> to travel by subwords in place of the full word default of `left/right-word` (the default commands for those keys).

It works as expected if I simply rebind the keys, except for one case:  If I try to "transient-mark" using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Right</kbd>, rather than marking the full word like `right-word` does, the point is moved to the next subword without creating a region.

Is this due to Subword Mode?  I would like to know if I can somehow combine some of the normal features of `left/right-word` like marking with the movement of Subword Mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO this is indeed a problem with `subword-mode`.  You can fix it by doing:

```
(defadvice subword-backward (before handle-shift-selection activate)
  (handle-shift-selection))

(defadvice subword-forward (before handle-shift-selection activate)
  (handle-shift-selection))
```

But my advice is to do also a `M-x report-emacs-bug` so this can be properly fixed in next release.

Comment: +1 to reporting this as a bug (or enhancement request), via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.